# Running app on two android emulators

Tags: android, emulation

Is it possible to run an app on two emulators. I have managed to successfully launch two separate emulators, (One Nexus 5X API 23 and Nexus 6 API 23), but the second emulator does not launch the actual app. It boots up, but the app is nowhere in site even in the app list. I have tried looking around for help on the matter but there is contradictory information. Can someone help me out?

Using Android Studio 2.1.2

Comment: Have you installed it on both emulators?  They are different VMs, you can't just install it on one.

Comment: If you try to open in one device, for example in the second, the apps is started?

Comment: @Gaston Flores No it does not appear in the second Nexus 6